# Ajax ActionLink Post Acting Like Get

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 application. I have an Ajax ActionLink in a view designed to Post some information back to a controller action. I need the Ajax ActionLink because I was previously doing a GET with a regular Html.ActionLink but I don't want the parameter visible in the querystring sent to the server. The Ajax ActionLink code is:

```
Ajax.ActionLink("C/C", "CCSettings", new { loadHeaderID = DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "LoadHeaderID") }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" })
```

This ends up inserting the following HTML into the page:

```
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Post" href="/LoadBoard/CCSettings?loadHeaderID=660">C/C</a>
```

My controller is decorated with HttpPost, as follows

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CCSettings(int loadHeaderID)
    {.....return View() }
```

Clicking the Ajax ActionLink gives me a 404 Error; i.e. Resource Cannot Be Found. The HttpPost appears to be preventing access to the controller. However, when I replace [HttpPost] with [HttpGet] the controller is accessed and the View is returned, however the parameter is displayed in the querystring, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

I'm sure I'm making a simple (and amateurish) error here, but I can't seem to "bend" the ActionLink to do what I want, which is POST to the controller so as to hide the parameter. I've tried doing this in Javascript with an Ajax postback but, while that lets me access the controller when it's decorated with HttpPost, I can't return the View.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Out of interest, have you checked to see if it is actually doing a partial get?  if you use chrome, go to the network tab in the inspector and see if the request is made by jquery.  if it isn't, then the link is doing a normal get, which is why it is failing

Comment: Yes, I can see clearly it is doing a GET (it's using the href in the link, with the QueryString). I just can't figure out why that href is being generated like that or how to change it. If I can't get around this (I need to hide that parameter) then there's a lot of work ahead of me. Thanks for posting and trying to help me out.

Comment: After more experimenting, the reason appears to be that jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js wasn't available, even though I had included it in a bundle. I then included it separately and now the ActionLink is doing a Post but it throws an error that it can't find the resource. My guess is it has something to do with the QueryString on the URL, I can't figure out why that's the href being generated but come to think of it I don't know how it's supposed to do a POST and pass that parameter otherwise. Back to the drawing board. :) Thanks for trying to help.